# How to load a WMS layer in Google Maps API?

Tags: wms, google-maps

I wanted to expand my knowledge on the google maps API and get a hang of pulling in WMS layers. I have set up a simple map window and want to pull in a layer that contains electorate boundaries so they can be viewed.

I was looking through the documentation and tried my hand doing it as a GroundOverlay but cannot seem to get it working.

The WMS Url i'm trying to use is from:

http://data.gov.au/dataset/wa-state-electoral-boundaries-psma-administrative-boundaries/resource/b30c4ca8-f506-459c-b6d5-3df207e8666b

and my current code is:

```
function myMap() {
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-31.9505, 115.8605), 
        zoom: 10,

    }
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);


var overlay;
var imageBounds = {
    north: -13.67856638945,
    south: -35.1350604142437,
    east: 129.00192884357,
    west: 112.920934694525
    };



    overlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay('http://data.gov.au/geoserver/wa-state-electoral-boundaries-psma-administrative-boundaries/wms?request=GetCapabilities',imageBounds);
    overlay.setMap(map);

    }
```

I guess I am just looking for a little prod in the right direction as to how to pull in a WMS with a URL like this. Am I looking at the wrong function entirely? I don't mind reading through the documentation and doing some self learning but just having trouble finding a starting point.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354163/google-map-api-3-wms

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: You should drop all request parameters (i.e. all name=value& parts) from the service URL.  So the service URL becomes: `http://data.gov.au/geoserver/wa-state-electoral-boundaries-psma-administrative-boundaries/wms?`